# Rename the Custom Links Section

Tags: custom-link

I want to rename the custom link section to say just "Links". Is that possible in Salesforce?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Is this a section on the object layout?

Comment: I don't think so. You may need to create a section yourself for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can change the section title to what you want when you edit your page layout..

Edit your object page layout, click on Custom links section and then click the Tools Icon on the right which will bring you this screen where you can change the section title.

[image]